# How to Make loop procesing faster when nested

Tags: batch-file

1.How to Make loop processing faster when nested.It takes 30 second to processing 1 character from (a) to (zzzzz)

2.how to make this code able to set range ,like start 2 digits and ended at 4 digits.

3.why this code display  coding commands ,that why i put character @ at from commands

Sample.bat

```
@echo off     
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion     

set "loop2=IN (0,1,36) DO @("     

set "n0="           
set "n1=a"     
set "n2=b"     
set "n3=c"     
set "n4=d"     
set "n5=e"     
set "n6=f"     
set "n7=g"     
set "n8=h"     
set "n9=i"     
set "n10=j"     
set "n11=k"     
set "n12=l"     
set "n13=m"     
set "n14=n"     
set "n15=o"     
set "n16=p"     
set "n17=q"     
set "n18=r"     
set "n19=s"     
set "n20=t"
set "n21=u"     
set "n22=v"     
set "n23=w"     
set "n24=x"     
set "n25=y"     
set "n26=z"     

set "n27=1"     
set "n28=2"     
set "n29=3"     
set "n30=4"     
set "n31=5"
set "n32=6"     
set "n33=7"     
set "n34=8"     
set "n35=9"     
set "n36=0"     

@FOR /L %%a %loop2%     
    @call :prc %%a      
    @FOR /L %%b %loop2%     
        @call :prc %%a %%b     
        @FOR /L %%c %loop2%     
            @call :prc %%a %%b %%c     
            @FOR /L %%d %loop2%     
                @call :prc %%a  %%b %%c %%d     
                @FOR /L %%e %loop2%     
                    @call :prc %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e     
                )     
            )     
        )     
    )     
)     
)     
@pause     
:prc     
::@cls     
@title %1 %2 %3 = !n%1!!n%2!!n%3!      
@set "data=!n%1!!n%2!!n%3!!n%4!!n%5!"      
@if not defined data goto end     
@echo.     
@echo %data% >> data.txt     
@echo.     
@:end     
@goto :eof     
`
```

Comment: You'll better explain what you need as final output !

Comment: I've updated your code to add indents where required, it appears to show that you have unbalanced parentheses!

Comment: ' SachaDee " i already got the output ,what i need is a code do process more faster,it slower because repeat same commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How to Make loop processing faster when nested?
   Remove any unneccessary command.
2. How to make this code able to set range?
   Take a different, recursive approach build up a string,
   looks like working on a diff. number base.
   BTW 36 power 5 is 60.466.176 and usually you start with
   number 0 and follow with letters after nine like hexadecimal 0-9abcdef
3. Why this code display coding commands?
   Doesn't happen here with `Echo off`

Disabled file output, just writing to console and
starting with the first letter.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "n= abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
for /l %%n in (1,1,36) do set "n%%n=!n:~%%n,1!"
set "n="

set "loop2=in (1,1,36) DO ("

FOR /L %%a %loop2%
    call :prc %%a
    FOR /L %%b %loop2%
        call :prc %%a %%b
        FOR /L %%c %loop2%
            call :prc %%a %%b %%c
            FOR /L %%d %loop2%
                call :prc %%a %%b %%c %%d
                FOR /L %%e %loop2%
                    call :prc %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e
                )
            Pause
            )
        )
    )
)
pause
Goto :Eof
:prc
set "data=!n%1!!n%2!!n%3!!n%4!!n%5!"
echo %data% &Rem>> data.txt
goto :eof
```

Comment: 1).THANKSSSS ,you made it from 30 second/1 character to 1 second/ to more than 30 character. 2).maybe i should try different method. 3) that weird why it only happen to my code. ...Thank again.....

Comment: You should follow your own advice ;-)  The data variable serves no purpose, meaning the :prc routine becomes a single line of code, so no need for a CALL - simply put the ECHO within each loop. Eliminating CALL and SET will have large impact in performance.

Comment: Of course, but without knowing beforehand what OPs intention is I didn't want to modify too much.

Comment: The ECHO ON problem is real, even for your code, and is easily fixed. See my answer.

Comment: @dbenham Good catch, didn't think of that and due to pausing didn't run up to 'on'.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out why ECHO OFF sometimes appears not to work - When you are printing a two digit string you eventually reach "on", which yields `echo on`. It should be obvious why this is a problem!

You should use a safe form of ECHO, the best of which is `echo(` - it looks weird, but it works.

Thinking of optimized performance, Aacini's solution was the first idea that popped into my head. But if you really want the best possible performance, you should completely eliminate environment variable expansion within the loops. This is easily done by switching to a simple FOR that iterates the symbols (digits) directly.

You stated you wanted to control the minimum and maximum number of digits printed for each string. That can easily be done with the addition of some IF statements. But IF takes time to execute. Better to dynamically build the entire set of nested loops as a single string of code. That way your main loops are always optimized to do the least amount of work possible.

Here is my optimized version. I arbitrarily limited the maximum number of digits to 5, as you had in your original code. That can be expanded quite easily, although the final code must fit within ~8192 characters. In theory that supports strings up to 68 digits, but it will be remarkable if humankind still exists on this planet when that program completes! Hell, earth will probably be long gone by then!

```
:: %1 = min number of digits, between 1 and 5. Default = 1
:: %2 = max number of digits, between 1 and 5. Default = 5
::
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Configuration
set /a "min=1, max=5"
if "%~1" neq "" set "min=%~1"
if "%~2" neq "" set "max=%~2"
if %min% lss 1 set min=1
if %max% lss 1 set min=1
if %min% gtr 5 set min=5
if %max% gtr 5 set max=5

:: Define symbols to be iterated by simple FOR
:: Use of simple FOR improves performance by eliminating environment variable
:: dereferencing within main loops.
set "chars=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0"

:: Dynamically build code as a "macro"
:: This enables configuration of number of digits printed, yet improves performance
:: by avoiding IF within main loops.
set "code="
set "digits="
for /l %%N in (1 1 %max%) do (
  set "code=!code!for %%%%N in (%chars%) do "
  set "digits=!digits!%%%%N"
  if %%N geq %min% (
    set "code=!code!echo(!digits!"
    if %%N lss %max% set "code=!code!&"
  )
)

:: Show the resultant code
echo !code!

:: Execute the code
>data.txt (%code%)
```

Using a min value of 1 and max of 4, it takes 35 seconds to complete on my machine. Increasing the max to 5 would take at least 21 minutes. By comparison, eliminate the inner loop from Aacini's code, fix the ECHO ON issue, and it takes 85 seconds to generate all strings from length 1 to 4 on my machine.

Below is the code that is generated by min=2, max=3, which takes only 1 second to complete. I intentionally used a quote block instead of code block to avoid excessive horizontal scrolling.

> for %1 in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) do for %2 in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) do echo(%1%2&for %3 in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) do echo(%1%2%3

Note that the above is the code after `%code%` has been expanded, so `%1` represents a FOR variable, not the first batch script argument.

Comment: sometimes, I'm not sure, what suprises me more - the weirdness of `cmd` or your capability to turn it into something useful...

Comment: @Stephan  :-)  Thanks. You pretty much captured the essence of why I enjoy working with batch.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the recommendations given in [LotPings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710617/778560), there are two constructs that are particularly slow:

- `call` command. If you want speed, avoid call subroutines. You may use a *macro* (like your original `loop2` variable, but with complete commands) instead.
- `>>` redirection. This form perform these steps each time it is used: 1-Open the file. 2-Seek for the file's end. 3-Append the data. 4-Close the file. It is *much faster* to use a unique `>` redirection that keep the file open all the time until the process ends.

I also modified your code in order to make it more readable:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "i=0"
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "n!i!=%%a"
)

set "range2=1,1,36"

(FOR /L %%a IN (%range2%) DO (
    echo !n%%a!
    FOR /L %%b IN (%range2%) DO (
        echo !n%%a!!n%%b!
        FOR /L %%c IN (%range2%) DO (
            echo !n%%a!!n%%b!!n%%c!
            FOR /L %%d IN (%range2%) DO (
                echo !n%%a!!n%%b!!n%%c!!n%%d!
                FOR /L %%e IN (%range2%) DO (
                    echo !n%%a!!n%%b!!n%%c!!n%%d!!n%%e!
                )
            )
        )
    )
)) > data.txt
```

Comment: Thank Aacini for explained . Actually  " >> redirection " i Doesn't need it. .its just for test the output ..but until now i still not clearly understand why my code  too slower,maybe because character @ .................THANKS

Comment: no, it's slower because you open `data.txt`, write a single element and close it again, repeating this thousands of times, where Aacini's solution just opens the file once, writes th whole data and closes the file, which is *much* faster.

Comment: Sooorryyyyyy ,after i read again Aacini answer ,now i understand what happen to my code  ,,,,thankss

Comment: Mmmm... IMHO my solution run _much faster_ than the one in the other answer... Doesn't it deserve an upvote at least? **`:/`**

Comment: The ECHO ON problem is real, even for your code, and is easily fixed. See my answer.